# Copy a file with the web interface

Tags: google-drive

I want to copy a file in my Google Drive using the web interface. Adding it to another folder seems to create a hard link rather than a file that can be changed independently of the original. There doesn't appear to be an action with a name like "copy," "duplicate," or "clone."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. While editing the document open the **File** menu and select **Make a copy...**

[image: Google Drive screen shot]

You can optionally copy the collaborators from the original document. Comments are not copied.

[image: Google Drive screen shot]

Comment: What about files that have been synced, like `.mp4` files for instance?

Answer (score 5):

It appears Google have made this very difficult, I guess to stop the accidental creation of various versions of documents.

If the file is a Google format, you can open it and select *File* → *Make a copy* to duplicate it.

If it isn't, the only work around I've seen within the web interface is [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/OBn9Q0AgDjM) cumbersome solution. (Only for files smaller than 25Mb.)

> Right click file name in Google Drive > Share > Email as Attachment to yourself > open file in Email > Rename > save to Drive

Comment: If it isn't, you can right-click on the file and choose "make a copy"

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work for folders, but you can Right-Click each file and "Make a copy", which you can then drag-n-drop to your new destination. Although lots of clicking, I'm using this method.

Comment: The Original Poster's question wasn't about folders. How does you answer differ to those already posted?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra This is the only answer to mention the "make a copy" solution for files that aren't a Doc or a Spreadsheet...

Answer (score 0):

If you select a file then hold control (CTRL) key and click "move to" google drive will create a hard-link of sort so the file will appear in both locations but if delete from either location it will delete the file i think.

Comment: Yes, and what's the most confusing about it is when any of these "multihomed" files get synced to the hard drive. Once you delete a local copy of the synced multihomed file, and the file will disappear from all its locations.

Answer (score 0):

Open Google Drive in the browser and select one or more files or folders.

You can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on Windows, or <kbd>cmd</kbd> key on Mac, to select non-consecutive files and folders. Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and you'll see an *Add to Folder* pop-up.

Select the folder where you wish to place the selected files and click OK.

Comment: I believe this is what the OP has tried.

Comment: WARNING! Guys, this operation will create a *link*, not a *copy*. This isn't a widely advertised feature of Google Drive, has its pluses and minuses. But `Shift+Z`, then "Add to..." will *NOT* make a separate copy.

Answer (score -2):

There is a workaround to this. If you have Microsoft SkyDrive, put your Google sync folder inside the SkyDrive and do your copying from within SkyDrive.