# Is it possible to copy a document in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Drive: copy a file with the web interface](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29503/google-drive-copy-a-file-with-the-web-interface)

In Google Docs (Drive) can you create a new document that is a copy of an existing document?